# ProGuard Build Warning - org.apache.http.entity

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I get following build error and more of the same:

```
Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity: can't find referenced method 'org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Body getBody()' in program class org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart
```

**But I have in my ProGuard Rules:**

-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }

-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }

Sow why do I get this warnings and build is failed?

Comment: Are you using `MultipartEntity`? Apache was removed as of API 23.

Comment: I don't know. I don't use it directly. I use the ZenDesk SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Because `org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Body` is an Intarface. Update your ProGuard Rules like this,

```
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keep interface org.apache.** { *; }
-keep enum org.apache.** { *; }
```

Add `-keep` for interfaces and enums wherever needed.

Comment: No, it does not work. Now I get this:
Warning:org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.james.mime4j.message.BodyPart
Warning:org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Multipart
and so on....
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Comment: Because the system is minifying `org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart`. So, you have to add `-keep` for `org.apache.http.** { *; }` also

Comment: Find the updated answer. Just keep `org.apache.** { *; }` so that everything comes under it will be excluded from minification process

Comment: Does also not work. Will try to add a question in the Zendesk forum.